# Trying to set screen brightness on android phone

Tags: android, null, window, screen, brightness

I am trying to set the screen brightness but when I try and get the current window with this.getWindow() I get null. Why is this? I will post all of my code in my setBrightness() method.

```
System.putInt(getContentResolver(), System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
            brightness);
Window window = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = brightness / (float) 255;
window.setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: Are you calling `getWindow()` from an `OnClickListener()` or something similar?

Comment: No just an activity. The activity is not visible and the method is called from another class that receives a notification from the main activity class. I actually wanted it to just be normal class but it seemed that it had to be an activity so it could access the getWindow() method?

Comment: here is the simple way to do it hope it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937365/increasing-screen-brightness-for-activity/21829712#21829712

Answer (score 0):

Don't use System.putInt()... You already set the screenBrightness in the lp!

The following code works:

```
Window window = getWindow();
float brightness = 100.0f;
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = brightness/255.0f;
window.setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Still getting null from getWindow() though. Maybe I am retrieving the wrong window somehow?

Comment: verify your imports i think you should import android.view.Window

Comment: These are my view imports:
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;

Comment: when you call the method getwindow() ; is it on your onCreate() method ?

Comment: No it is in a different method.

Comment: is that method is on your Activity Class or another class? if yes , so you should pass the Context to your second class ,please add de code of your method and the name of the class that contains this method , :)

Comment: it seems that you calling the getWindow() method from another class which is not an Activity , so you should pass the context to the second Class, the constructor of your class will be : public SecondClass(Context _context){ this.context = _context; } , and then you should call the getWindow() method by using the variable context like this : this.context.getWindow(); hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a seekbar, try these lines,

```
System.putInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float)255;
window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call it from fragment add getActivity() before getWindow() like this

```
getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

And if use seekbar dont let your brogress be 0, cause it can make your screen goes completly dark(on android 2.3)